# Group bus prefix fails connectivity on ERC [Kicad 7.0] [Win11]

Tags: kicad

Kicad 7.0 fails bus entry when I give a bus any prefix(name).
When naming bus, I have to use naming formula (example): {SPI_CLK SPI_MOSI SPI_MISO SPI_SS}

This works, anyway if I add prefix, for example SPI{SPI_CLK SPI_MOSI SPI_MISO SPI_SS} it stops, i.e. Eletrical Rules Checker cries: "Error: Label SPI_CLK not connected to anything" and this applies to all signals in the bus.

Did anyone found the solution to give a name to bus or shorten bus name and still not failing with later ERC?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In KiCad 7, the best way to accomplish this is to use "Bus Alias".  You can find these in your Schematic Setup.

[image: Bus Alias Example]